# How to convert nvarchar datetime into datetime in SQL sever 2008?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table where activedate is the nvarchar column which I need to convert into datetime to compare with another datetime field. My current data is in the following format:

```
3/19/2013 4:18:59
```

I have tried this:

```
     alter table [stresstest].[dbo].[temporaryVSDB]
     alter column activateDate datetime;
```

and

```
  convert(datetime,activateDate,101)
```

But not working.

I am getting the following error message:

```
    Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

please help.

Comment: And what exactly is 'not working'? Are you getting an error message? Are there maybe invalid datetime formats in the column `activateDate`?

Comment: what does 'not working' mean? any error message?

Comment: @barsan I am confused do you want to convert values of column in table DateTime during comparison or you want to change it permanently ? because in first scenario you can use either `CAST` or `CONVERT` function both will work.

Comment: @Barsan it's would be better to us if you clear your question. do you want change column datatype of just want to convert varchar to datetime for comparision

Answer (score 0):

Likely because 3rd opf whatever is the 19th month is not a validadatetime.

RTFM says that format 101 is: mm/dd/yyyy - which looks like date only to me.

TIme including formats have other format codes that you can see in the table at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx (which means: The documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Simply set Dateformat before given or insert value(s) of datetime.

check it out.

```
declare @t table(dtcolumn datetime)

set dateformat mdy
insert into @t values('3/19/2013 4:18:59')

select * from @t
```

Answer (score 0):

Your system is not set to [MDY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189491%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) format for DateTime thats why you are getting this error.
Try changing your Date Format.

```
SET DATEFORMAT MDY;
SELECT CAST('19/3/2013 4:18:59' AS DATETIME)
```

However, SET `DATEFORMAT` overrides the implicit date format setting of [SET LANGUAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms174398.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should not store a datatime as a nvarchar or any other character type. Datetime belongs in a datetime field. If you convert it while comparing it, you get a terrible performance. 
If you are stuck with the current datamodel you could add a new computed field. Here is the conversion to a PERSISTED computed column. PERSISTED computed columns has the advanage of having an actual value which can be indexed.

This example looks like hell. It will however calculate your field. It would be easy to use a normal computed column, but it will result in performance issues. This will require that all the values in YourColumn has valid datetime values.

```
CREATE TABLE #t(YourColumn varchar(18))
INSERT #t
values ('3/19/2013 4:18:59'),
       ('3/9/2013 5:18:59'),
       ('01/9/2013 6:18:59'),
       ('12/9/2013 17:18:59')


ALTER TABLE #t 
ADD CDateColumn AS 
  CONVERT(datetime, 
  LEFT(STUFF(YourColumn, 1, CHARINDEX('/', YourColumn, 4), ''), 4)
  +'-' + SUBSTRING('0' + YourColumn, PATINDEX('%__/%', ' ' +YourColumn), 2) + '-'
  +RIGHT('0'+REPLACE(LEFT(STUFF(YourColumn, 1, CHARINDEX('/', YourColumn), ''), 2), '/', ''), 2) + 'T'
  +RIGHT('0'+REPLACE(LEFT(STUFF(YourColumn, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', YourColumn), ''), 2), ':', ''), 2)
  +RIGHT(YourColumn, 6), 126) PERSISTED
```

Result will be:

```
SELECT * FROM #t

YourColumn          CDateColumn
3/19/2013 4:18:59   2013-03-19 04:18:59.000
3/9/2013 5:18:59    2013-03-09 05:18:59.000
01/9/2013 6:18:59   2013-01-09 06:18:59.000
12/9/2013 17:18:59  2013-12-09 17:18:59.000
```

NB: Your current script will work if you change it to:

```
CONVERT(datetime,activateDate,0)
```